# Positive semi-definite matrix and exponent of its entries

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $(a_{ij})_{i,j=1,...,n}$ be a symmetric positive semi-definite matrix with real entries. Is the matrix $(\exp(a_{ij}))_{i,j=1,...,n}$ a positive semi-definite?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Schur product theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_product_theorem) states that the Hadamard (i.e. entrywise) product of two positive definite matrices is positive definite.

It follows that the entrywise exponential of a positive definite matrix is positive definite. By continuity, the entrywise exponential of a positive semidefinite matrix is positive semidefinite.

Comment: Hot damn!  That's a neat trick.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, it is at least true that if a $2 \times 2$ matrix with non-negative entries is symmetric and positive definite, then so is its entry-wise exponential.  This follows from the AM-GM inequality.

<s>I don't believe that this holds</s> Apparently this holds in general. I don't have a proof either way, but I thought the partial result was worth posting.

Comment: In the paper "Berg, Christensen, Positive definite functions on abelian semigroups, Math. Ann., 1976, 253-272", authors used this fact in the proof of the Proposition 3.2

Comment: The fact in your question or the fact that I've stated?

Comment: According to these authors, my question has affirmative answer.

Comment: Oh, interesting.  Do the authors not provide a reference?

Comment: That is a sad thing

Comment: @Omnomnomnom : If the matrix is diagonal, then we can conclude directly. Since the matrix is unitarily diagonalizable by spectral theorem, we can first diagonalize it and then for the diagonal matrix, the result holds. But I'm not sure if positive-definiteness is preserved under unitary similarity. Can you please comment on this approach ?

Comment: @Srinivas K: note that similar operators have same spectra and hence all the eigenvalues will be unchanged